# Problem with permitAll in Vaadin and WebSecurity - not working

Tags: java, spring-security, vaadin

I have few views made in Vaadin by @Route and now I want to add Security and some Login. In my `SecurityConfiguration` class I'm setting `antMatchers.permitAll()` only for 2 views and for the rest with Role `ADMIN`. But it is not working as I think it should. It demands login to access every view, and after login I have access to all views no matter what role has the user.

I hoped this tutorial will help me, but in there are no views accessible without login.

[Securing Your App With Spring Security](https://vaadin.com/tutorials/securing-your-app-with-spring-security)

## My configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private UserService userService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfiguration(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Autowired
    private void configureAuth(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService);
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("user"))
                .roles("USER");
    }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.httpBasic().and()
              .anonymous()
              .and()
              .authorizeRequests()
              .antMatchers("/", "/login").permitAll()
              .antMatchers("/recipe-manager", "/ingredient-manager").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
              .and()
              .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
              .and()
              .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/")
              .and()
              .csrf().disable().cors().disable().headers().disable();
  }
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(
                "/VAADIN/**",
                "/favicon.ico",
                "/robots.txt",
                "/manifest.webmanifest",
                "/sw.js",
                "/offline-page.html",
                "/icons/**",
                "/images/**",
                "/frontend/**",
                "/webjars/**",
                "/h2-console/**",
                "/frontend-es5/**", "/frontend-es6/**");
    }
}
```

My Views have annotations like:

```
@Route("recipe-manager")
public class RecipeManagerView extends VerticalLayout
@Route("")
public class RecipeBrowserView extends VerticalLayout 
@Route("login")
public class LoginView extends VerticalLayout 
@Route("ingredient-manager")
public class IngredientManagerView extends VerticalLayout
```

I would expect that anyone can have access to `RecipeBrowserView` and `LoginView`, but only logged user can have access to `RecipeManagerView` and `IngredientMangerView`.

Comment: What happened when you try to access the LoginView?

Comment: Well when I'm logged I'm redirected to LoginView, when I'm not logget nothing - I'm there anywhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use path based matching from Spring Security for Vaadin routes. Spring Security does the matching based on request paths whereas navigation from one view to another inside Vaadin is sent as metadata inside an internal request that always goes to the same hardcoded path.

Instead, you can implement your access control logic in an interceptor provided by Vaadin. You can have a look at https://vaadin.com/tutorials/securing-your-app-with-spring-security to find out more about this.

Comment: Ok,thanks for advice. I'm looking at it again. Now knowing that the solutions should be there. But I can't really figure out how to do it. Should I do it somehow in ConfigureUISeriveInitListener.class in method beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent event)?

Comment: Seems like I'm living in the future. The tutorial series is still work in progress and the part about router integration is not yet completed. You are right about the idea of using a UI-level beforeEnter listener registered from a service init listener. You can see an example of how this can be done already today if you download the full stack ("bakery") starter from vaadin.com/start.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding `antMatchers` only accept single arguments. You should change you configuration class like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private UserService userService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfiguration(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Autowired
    private void configureAuth(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService);
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("user"))
                .roles("USER");
    }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.httpBasic().and()
              .anonymous()
              .and()
              .authorizeRequests()
              .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
              .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
              .antMatchers("/recipe-manager", "/ingredient-manager").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
              .and()
              .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
              .and()
              .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/")
              .and()
              .csrf().disable().cors().disable().headers().disable();
  }
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(
                "/VAADIN/**",
                "/favicon.ico",
                "/robots.txt",
                "/manifest.webmanifest",
                "/sw.js",
                "/offline-page.html",
                "/icons/**",
                "/images/**",
                "/frontend/**",
                "/webjars/**",
                "/h2-console/**",
                "/frontend-es5/**", "/frontend-es6/**");
    }
}
```

Comment: I've changed but it is not it. And andMatchers takes Varargs of String so there can be multiple patterns.